# How to specify separate chunkSize for ItemReader and ItemWriter in spring batch?

Tags: spring-batch

I'm new to spring batch. Can someone please let me know if there is anyway to set separate chunk sizes or ItemReader and ItemWriter ? If I do the below way, both read and write chunk size is set to 10.

```
@Bean
public Step sampleStep(PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager) {
        return this.stepBuilderFactory.get("sampleStep")
                                .transactionManager(transactionManager)
                                .<String, String>chunk(10)
                                .reader(itemReader())
                                .writer(itemWriter())
                                .build();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That is not possible by design. A chunk oriented step is configured with a single chunk size (commit-interval) which is the same for the entire step. More details about chunk processing in Spring Batch here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.0.x/reference/html/step.html#chunkOrientedProcessing